# Charcoal/mock up like border effect with CSS3

Tags: html, css, border

Is there a way to draw "charcoal like" borders with CSS3? These kind of lines are popular in many mock-up tools as they symbolize work in design phase.

E.g. images here

http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups

- Line may not be straight and has some "twist" in it
- Line has boldness in it
- Brush effect: line may contain individual white pixels in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Variant** beat me to it, but as he mentioned, you can create quite a similar effect with the `border-image` property. Examples:

http://hertzen.com/experiments/css-charcoal-borders/ (it is just using a single image for all elements)

With my approach, the border images outer bit is colored `white`, so applying a `background-color` to the element will color the contents of the element inside it, leaving the outer bit `white`. If you need to get it working on multiple different background colors (requiring you to have transparancy inside and outside of the `border-image`), then you can create an element behind the current element, which is within the borders, and assign the `background-color` there.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this effect with CSS3's `border-image` property.

You can see some samples here: 
http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

and here:
https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/